# Linear algebra: Transformation matrix to reflect all points about a plane with given equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The transformation $T$ that maps every point in $\mathbb{R}^3$ into its reflection in the plane $x + y – 2z = 0$ is linear. Find its $3\times3$ matrix. As a check take a point on the plane and see if $T$ maps it to itself.

I understand someone already asked this question, but he/she didn't show any work. I have the same question and I would like to get help with it. Here is what I have so far:

$\text{normal of plane given} = (1,1,-2)$,
a point in the plane would be $\text{normal} \cdot (a,b,c) = 0$ but I'm unsure if this gets me anywhere. Thank you.

Comment: You also need to find two vectors which span the plane.  Then figure out geometrically what the image of each of those three vectors are under $T$.

Comment: If you have any orthonormal set $\{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$ of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the following holds for any vector $v$: $v = (v \dots e_1)e_1 + (v \cdot e_2) e_2 + (v \cdot e_3) e_3$ (since $(v\cdot e_i)e_i$ is just the part of $v$ that points in the $e_i$ direction). Your normal vector will (almost – what’s wrong?) be an element of an orthonormal set, but you only want the other parts. If you understand this, it will lead to a very easy solution of your problem, but if you don’t, it is probably better to do calculations that you do understand.

Comment: @Bye_World Finding a basis for the plane isn’t really necessary in order to compute $T$’s matrix.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You can decompose any vector $v$ into $k(1,1,-2)+w$, where $w$ is a vector in the given plane. What does $T$ do to each of these components?